# Синхронизация проектов локального и удаленного репозитория git

Tags: git

Имеем TortoiseGit и аккаунт на bitbaket.
В проекте на контроль установлены только файлы изменяемые разработчиком. Файлы генерируемые  IDE в gitignore. При коммите проекта на bitbaket, там хранятся только файлы на контроле. Т.е. в удаленном репозитории хранится только часть проекта. При утере локального репозитория восстановить проект из локального репозитория не возможно. Какие варианты разрешения этой ситуации могут быть?

Comment: "При утере локального репозитория восстановить проект из локального репозитория не возможно" - какой смысл вы вложили в эту фразу?

Comment: Клонировать проект из удаленного репозитория, нет?

Comment: Если на контроле стоит не весь проект, а только часть? В удаленном репозитории ханятся только файлы, которые на контроле.